# Newbie trying to learn how to connect to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have one file on one web serve and my phpmyadmin SQL databases on a seperate server and am currently trying to connect to my external serve but it doesnt seem to work.

I keep getting the error message:

> 'Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

and am not sure what this means.

Any help would be greatly appreciated or even an article to get started on figuring this out since I cant seem to find anything myself.

Thank you

EDIT  --- PDO SCRIPT ---

My PDO Script is the generic one from w3, I have place holders for security reasons.

```
<?php
    $servername = "externalIP";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=Reservations", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


?>
```

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.

Comment: I'm guessing you have phpmyadmin (it's just a php script) and the mysql database on two separate servers. If that's the case then phpmyadmin is trying to connect to the server it's running on (localhost means _this_ server). You need to connect to the mysql database using its domain name or ip.

Comment: It means you're trying to connect to your database without credentials, which (as it should!) doesn't work. Aside from that, you'll have to make sure your mysql server accepts connections outside of localhost

Comment: My phpMyAdmin user is set to use any host, is that the same as allowing any connection? sorry its all new to me and I am using credentials in my PDO script that have access to the database I am trying to connect to.

Comment: Then please show us your PDO script so we might be able to see what's going on.

Comment: Posted it as an edit.

Comment: Well there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that code. It's odd though that is says a **user** is trying to connect without using a password. Something must be going wrong there. But it's hard to figure out what it is without seeing it myself.

Comment: If you could in a brief really short walkthrough, just post a phpmyadmin way of creating the user for something like this. I would just like to know if maybe its a problem with the user credentials and not the code.

Comment: To create a new user, click the Add a new user link near the bottom of the Privileges page (you must be a "superuser", e.g., user "root"). Use the textboxes and drop-downs to configure the user to your particular needs. You can then select whether to create a database for that user and grant specific global privileges. Once you've created the user (by clicking Go), you can define that user's permissions on a specific database (don't grant global privileges in that case). In general, users do not need any global privileges (other than USAGE), only permissions for their specific database.

Comment: @RyanVincent phpMyAdmin isn't the issue here. The issue is that he can't connect to the database with his own php script.

Answer (score 0):

you have to find your phpmyadmin page where you login using also a password.

Comment: I have a user setup specifically for a specific database that I am trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

if you have not assign password into database for specific user then you just have to apply 'root' as user and leave blank password field and also set your hostname as 'localhost' or 127.0.0.1

also remember that you have to start first apache and mysql services before access.

Comment: Do I still use local host as host name when it is an external server I am connecting to?

Comment: If you are use remote server for as database then not required.in that case you have to apply your remote ip address.

Comment: If it is external server then give ipaddress to connect the host

Comment: Yes Dear.for exa. your system in which you coding for mysql conntection and your db server system as remote machine then your code like this.$conn=mysqli_connect('192.x.x.x','root','','dbname');

Answer (score 0):

If you are using remote server as database then not required.in that case you have to apply your remote Ip address and also remember that in that remote server if you have not specific user then leave password as blank.

one another way to debug mysql connection  into your remote server creating mysql connection file with its required paramter to check that your remote server ok or not.

Answer (score 0):

This error will come most probably because of user permission issue. Make sure you have privilege to that user for that database.